# Updating a sprite co-ordinate based on its direction

Tags: javascript, sprite

I have a sprite representing a bullet and its basic implementation is as follows:

```
function Bullet(x, y, rotation) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.direction = rotation;
    this.speed = 5;
}

Bullet.prototype.update = function() {
    // Move the bullet forward
    this.x = Math.sin(this.rotation) * this.speed;
    this.x = Math.cos(this.rotation) * this.speed;
}
```

What I'm trying to do here is move the bullet forward in the direction it's facing and relative to its speed. However, when calling the `update()` method `this.x` and `this.x` is `NaN`.

What's the correct way of making a sprite move in the direction it's facing if given its `x`, `y` and `rotation` information?

Comment: Try implementing a `Vector` class. It'll make this stuff much easier to work with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a typo. This:

```
this.x = Math.sin(this.rotation) * this.speed;
```

should be

```
this.x = Math.sin(this.direction) * this.speed;
```

Comment: Right, this will also fix the problem.

Comment: Woops, I changed the variable name and missed that. Although it still doesn't work correctly, the bullets don't move from their x and y positions. :(